# button that will hide and unhide row one at a time. Something similar to spin button

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have searched threw many questions but can't find any answer to what i cam looking to do.
    I would like to hide and unhide rows.  I like spin button where you can click up and down arrow but If that doesn't work then one button to hide and other to unhide.

```
I have tried few VBA codes but none of them worked the way I want.

**1st VBA code**:  following code works to hide multiple rows but all at once not one at a time.  
If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
 'This area contains the things you want to happen
'when the toggle button is not depressed
Rows(4).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Rows(5).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Rows(6).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
'This area contains the things you want to happen
'when the toggle button is depressed
Rows(4).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Rows(5).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Rows(6).EntireRow.Hidden = False
 End If
2nd VBA code: Hide and unhides just one row.
If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
 'This area contains the things you want to happen
'when the toggle button is not depressed
Rows(4).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
'This area contains the things you want to happen
'when the toggle button is depressed
 Rows(4).EntireRow.Hidden = False
  End If



Someone please help!
```

Answer (score 2):

`SpinButton1` is an ActiveX spinbutton the worksheet (Min=0, Max=10 or however many rows you want to show/hide)

A7 here will be the top row of the set of rows to be shown/hidden

Code goes in the sheet module.

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()

    Dim r As Long, mx As Long
    r = Me.SpinButton1.Value
    mx = Me.SpinButton1.Max

    With Me.Range("A7")
        If r > 0 Then .Resize(r).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        If r < mx Then .Offset(r, 0).Resize(mx - r).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End With

End Sub
```